# HPA cannot get metrics due to 403 errors

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, horizontal-pod-autoscaling

I used the following metrics inside hpa

```
apiVersion: autoscaling/v2beta2
kind: HorizontalPodAutoscaler
metadata:
  name: app-svc-hpa
  namespace: default
spec:
  scaleTargetRef:
    apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
    kind: Deployment
    name: app-svc
  minReplicas: 1
  maxReplicas: 1000
  metrics:
  - type: Resource
    resource:
      name: cpu
      target:
        type: Utilization
        averageUtilization: 50
  - type: Pods
    pods:
      metric:
        name: packets-per-second
      target:
        type: AverageValue
        averageValue: 1k
```

But the hpa is unable to get the metrics

`Warning  FailedGetPodsMetric           14s (x6 over 1m)  horizontal-pod-autoscaler  unable to get metric packets-per-second: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: the server could not find the descriptor for metric custom.googleapis.com/packets-per-second: googleapi: Error 403: Permission monitoring.metricDescriptors.get denied (or the resource may not exist)., forbidden`

I am running the pods on a dedicated nodepool and each nodes is running under a service account.

The service account does have these iam roles

Monitoring Viewere,
Monitoring Metrics Writer

Unsure how to fix this error. Any pointers are greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: you mentioned IAM role, is it running on EKS? did you try to deploy with no serviceaccount? did you add the right privileges to the metric server?

Comment: it is running on Google Cloud Kubernetes Engine

Comment: Are you using RBAC in the current configuration?

Comment: No I am not using RBAC

Comment: Have you checked the metric server logs?

Comment: I ran the same hpa on a new cluster running under default service account and I see this new error

unable to get metric packets-per-second: unable to fetch metrics from custom metrics API: no custom metrics API (custom.metrics.k8s.io) registered

Any pointers ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/211305/discussion-between-varunkumar-manohar-and-mickey-hovel).

Comment: The error that you are encountering points to the either permission denied or lack of metric named `packets-per-second`. There is a GCP guide with very similar configuration like yours: [Cloud.google.com: HPA](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/docs/how-to/horizontal-pod-autoscaling). It mentions that `packets-per-second` is a custom metric that needs to be created. Did you create this metric?  Can you see this metric in `GCP->Monitoring->Metrics Explorer`?

Comment: Thank you that answers my question and there was yet another issue which I managed to find out why. I will post my answer below

Answer (score 1):

I had a cluster with `workload identity` enabled. Apparently when a cluster has workload identity enabled, the metrics fetch was failing.

1) I had to install the custom stack driver adapter and create the custom metric as pointed by David Kruk in his comments

2) I had to add the `hostNetwork:true` in the custom stackdriver adapter deployment pod spec. The issue is mentioned [here](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/k8s-stackdriver/issues/315) in github repository for csa

With these two updates, the autoscaler works as expected.