# getting error while implementing metric server inside the Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, hpa

"Failed to scrape node" `

```
err="GET \"https://10.128.0.17:10250/stats/summary? 
only_cpu_and_memory=true\": bad status code \"403 Forbidden\"" 
node="gke-zipydev-cluster-zipy-pool-b4bfa53a-t575"
I1215 10:33:03.405180       1 server.go:188] "Failed probe" 
probe="metric-storage-ready" err="not metrics to serve"
E1215 10:33:10.513042       1 scraper.go:139] "Failed to scrape 
node" err="GET \"https://10.128.0.16:10250/stats/summary? 
only_cpu_and_memory=true\": bad status code \"403 Forbidden\"" 
node="gke-zipydev-cluster-zipy-pool-b4bfa53a-sg4t"
```

please help if anyone faced same issue.

Comment: Did you had time to check the answer? It helped you to solve your problem? If yes, Please consider to accept and upvote it.

Answer (score 2):

The privileges for the metrics server are not correctly added as the “403“ error is because access to the requested resource is forbidden.

The Metrics Server requires the **“CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE”** capability in order to bind to a privileged ports as non-root as this applies even if you use the **--secure-port** flag to change the port that Metrics Server binds to to a non-privileged port. Refer [Security context](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server#security-context) for information.

As described in the [Github link](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/105938/files), Granting metrics-server necessary permissions to access(query/read) ***nodes/stat*** API resource is the workaround to solve this issue. You can grant metrics-server necessary permissions by using the below configuration file.

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: ClusterRole
metadata:
  name: system:metrics-server
rules:
  - apiGroups:
      - ""
    resources:
      - nodes/stats
      - nodes
    verbs:
      - get
      - list
```

**NOTE:** Check your metrics-server has a recent version if you installed it manually. In order to update your metrics-server deployment, you can refer to the [Github link](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/metrics-server/releases?page=1) and select the version which suits you.

Refer [stackpost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61125754/) for more information about 403 forbidden errors.